# Convert string[][] to int[][]

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am trying to simply convert the type of jagged arrays:

I would like to do it using something like:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = Array.ConvertAll(jaggedArrayString, int.Parse)
```

or

```
int[][] jaggedArray = Array.ConvertAll(jaggedArrayString, delegate(string s) { return int.Parse(s); }
```

With Linq, I can't do it that way either

```
int[][] jaggedArray = jaggedArrayString.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

I didn't find any solution, is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried plain old loops?

Comment: I'd like to have a more efficient solution for that

Comment: Who told you LINQ will always be more efficient than loops?

Comment: I think it depends on the human-readability and time spending on this task. I was pretty sure it's possible with LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ, you need to `Select` the strings in each sub array, so you need nested `Select`s:

```
int[][] result = arr.Select(x => 
                     x.Select(int.Parse).ToArray()
                 ).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's right, funny thing I just tried and it worked a few minutes ago before you answered :)

matrixFromFile1.Select(x => x.Select(y => int.Parse(y)).ToArray()).ToArray();
Thanks !